# Can the time a dream occurs influence its significance?

Tags: time, dream

Does the time during the day or night when one has a dream have any influence on how meaningful it is? I've heard it does, but have no good source, and wonder whether it's true.

Comment: Do you have any reason to think so? If so, please [edit](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/26419/edit) that reasoning into the question.

Comment: no reasons...I just heard about it a time ago, but the person didnt give me any source

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. The Gemara says (Berachot 55b) in the of Rabbi Yohanan that three dreams are fulfilled and of them is a dream that happened early in the morning. Maharsha says there that the reason is because all the things that happened the day before are usually dreamt about late at night and in the morning the mind is fresh to have a "real dream".

Comment: Thank you! What time is early? between alot hashachar and netz hachama? after netz hachama? or dont have a specific time?

Comment: I've heard HaRav Mizrahi say 6am but I'm not sure if he was being exact.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard that dreams on Friday have significance. I can't remember if that's Friday night (שבת) or Thursday night. No source.